# loading an image file hosted in assets folder exposed with web server in the app

Tags: javascript, java, android, webserver

In my app, I have created web server which is hosting a web app. All the files of web app are placed in assets folder.

Now, i start the web server by running my application and then from crome brower, I try to run my web app by calling index.html file. The html, css part of the page is getting loaded properly but the images are not getting loaded in the page:

Here is my HttpRequestHandlerCode:

```
public class HomePageHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
    private Context context = null;

    private static final Map<String, String> mimeTypes = new HashMap<String, String>() {

        {
            put("css", "text/css");
            put("htm", "text/html");
            put("html", "text/html");
            put("xhtml", "text/xhtml");
            put("xml", "text/xml");
            put("java", "text/x-java-source, text/java");
            put("md", "text/plain");
            put("txt", "text/plain");
            put("asc", "text/plain");
            put("gif", "image/gif");
            put("jpg", "image/jpeg");
            put("jpeg", "image/jpeg");
            put("png", "image/png");
            put("svg", "image/svg+xml");
            put("mp3", "audio/mpeg");
            put("m3u", "audio/mpeg-url");
            put("mp4", "video/mp4");
            put("ogv", "video/ogg");
            put("flv", "video/x-flv");
            put("mov", "video/quicktime");
            put("swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
            put("js", "application/javascript");
            put("pdf", "application/pdf");
            put("doc", "application/msword");
            put("ogg", "application/x-ogg");
            put("zip", "application/octet-stream");
            put("exe", "application/octet-stream");
            put("class", "application/octet-stream");
            put("m3u8", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
            put("ts", " video/mp2t");
        }
    };

    public HomePageHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        //String contentType = "text/html";
        //Log.i("Sushill", "..request : " + request.getRequestLine().getUri().toString());
        final String requestUri = request.getRequestLine().getUri().toString();
        final String contentType = contentType(requestUri);
                        String resp = Utility.openHTMLStringFromAssets(context, "html" + requestUri);
                        writer.write(resp);
                        writer.flush();
//                    }
                }
            });
            ((EntityTemplate) entity).setContentType(contentType);
            response.setEntity(entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get content type
     *
     * @param fileName
     *            The file
     * @return Content type
     */
    private String contentType(String fileName) {

        String ext = "";
        int idx = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (idx >= 0) {
            ext = fileName.substring(idx + 1);
        }
        if (mimeTypes.containsKey(ext)) {
            //Log.i("Sushill", "...ext : " + ext);
            return mimeTypes.get(ext);
        }
        else
            return "application/octet-stream";
    }
```

To handle image, I tried this but it did not work :

```
if(contentType.contains("image")) {
                    InputStream is = Utility.openImageFromAssets(context, "html" + requestUri);
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                    try {
                        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                        int n;
                        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out how to load the images also in my browser.

Thanks for any help

Comment: 'String resp = Utility.openHTMLStringFromAssets'. Ok, that is for the text files. Where is your code to serve image files?

Comment: @greenapps.. I tried writing some code to server for image files by writting the buffer, but still it did not help. Can you provide some sample code for serving image files?

Comment: Writing the buffer would be ok. So show the code you tried.

Comment: @greenapps .. I have edited my question to add my buffer code which did not work.

Comment: You are using UTF-8 conversion for an image. That will not do. Do away with the Buffering and readers. Read from InputStream 'is' directly.

Comment: @greenapps.. I have inputstream but was not sure how to use that. can you please mention what you are saying with few lines of code?outstreamwriter does not have an api which takes inputstream, so i converted it to buffer.. and what should I replace UTF-8 with? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I said 'do away with BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader' so you do away with UTF-8 too. Use only InputStream 'is'. Do away with writer. You are not showing what 'writer' is but do away with it. Use the OutputStream of the http connection. Keep the buffer and the loop where you read in the buffer and write from the buffer.

Comment: @greenapps.. tnaks for your comment. it worked with your suggestion. if you move your comment to answer, I will accept it. I just have one more doubt. My page has few buttons which are done with fonts in CSS. Initially i was thinking that is also image. but now i realized that they are fonts. They are still not showing up in my page. Can you please suggest how to make them work...

Comment: @greeapps.. the fonts also worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do away with BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader' so you do away with UTF-8 too. Use only InputStream 'is'. Do away with writer. You are not showing what 'writer' is but do away with it. Use the OutputStream of the http connection. Keep the buffer and the loop where you read in the buffer and write from the buffer.